# Is there a name for the design concept in which a function's parameter type enforces the constraints to eschew guard clauses?

Tags: function, design-patterns, typed, guard-clause

Suppose I have a (pseudo-code) function divideTwenty.

```
fn integer divideTwenty(int divisor) {
   return 20/divisor;
}
```

This function is simple, but error prone. Specifically, what if `divisor` is 0? What's the best way to deal with this? There are countless answers. But for now, well, we could add a guarding clause.

```
fn integer divideTwenty(int divisor) {
    if(divisor == 0) { 
        return -1; 
    }
    return 20/divisor;
}
```

This is still not great (can divisor be negative?), but let's just focus on the clause. There is an alternative approach, that accomplishes the same spirit. What if instead of passing `int divisor` we passed `NonZeroInteger divisor`?

That is,

```
class NonZeroInteger {
    int value;
    fn void init(int allegedNonZeroInteger) {
        if(allegedNonZeroInteger == 0) { throw InvalidArgumentException("Number is zero"); }
        self.value = allegedNonZeroInteger;
    }
}

fn integer divideTwenty(NonZeroInteger divisor) {
    return 20/divisor.value;
}
```

My question is very simple. Is there a specific name for this kind of design pattern? That is, where we create classes (or types) explicitly for the purposes of establishing constraints on the data being provided to functions. Is it just illustrative of the general use of typed programming, or OOP, encapsulation, or something else?

Thanks.

This isn't a troubleshooting problem. I'm just asking a question about code design concepts.

Comment: Note that your guard clause solution produces a different result than your typed solution. The guard clause results in *a value*, while the typed solution results in an exception, pretty much just like the original problem code did. In function programming, where a lot of this logic *is* implemented in types, just raising an exception wouldn't do though, it would basically be a compile-time error for incompatible types. In functional programming it would _look_ like your typed solution but behave more like your guard solution, in that a zero number would produce some "not a result" value.

Comment: "_Is it just illustrative of the general use of typed programming, or OOP?_" That's what I've always thought. And in that paradigm, the inverse is an anti-pattern called [primitive obsession](https://refactoring.guru/smells/primitive-obsession).

Comment: This seems possibly just like a side benefit of using objects over primitive types in general.  Objects allow you to choose from a particular set of entities, and you can use that to restrict what entities are allowed.  Usually, this is used for generalizing instead, for example if you wanted to create a complex number class that would generalize the primitive number types.  In this case it could also be used for specializing as with the non-zero divisors.

Comment: similar discussion here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/113576/is-hungarian-notation-a-workaround-for-languages-with-insufficiently-expressive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are describing a design-concept that is summarized as **"parse, don't validate"**. It is not exclusive to OOP and it works particularly well on immutable objects.

Your `NonZeroInteger`-class *parses* the int to be a `NonZeroInteger`. Parsing, in this case, means to take an input with few constraints and return an output with the same meaning but more constraints that you can rely on. Parsing might fail if the unstructured input does not fulfill the constraints. This is not what you usually think of when you read something like "Json-parser", but it is consistent with this definition.

Operations can now rely on the structure of `NonZeroInteger`. This is good, because the signature of `divideTwenty(NonZeroInteger)` now describes to the programmer and the compiler/type-checker what kind of inputs it can take, while the old `divideTwenty(int)` method actually only works on a subset of its statically allowed inputs.

Other formulations of this design-concept are **"make invalid state unrepresentable"** and the concept of preferring "complete functions" over "partial functions". You may look up "phantom types", they are a sophisticated implementation of this concept.

You can read an excellent and detailed article about it here, the examples are in haskell but you don't have to be a haskell-programmer to read it: https://lexi-lambda.github.io/blog/2019/11/05/parse-don-t-validate/

Comment: Greater answers, thanks.

Comment: Compelling blog post on this topic [here](https://www.awwsmm.com/blog/make-invalid-states-unrepresentable)

Comment: @AJSnow that is an interesting take. Though I would add: being overzealous with restricting data to be valid might kill some legitimate use-cases of your system that you didn't think of and that your users don't expect. I worked on a system where a weight had legitimate reasons to be negative and us programmers did not know it and the biz-side didn't think this was an important think to tell us because they expect that a number in a software can generally be negative.

Answer (score 1):

This is called **encapsulation**. Using OOP to encapsulate the data and behavior (validations and logic) in the objects. It is encouraged to use it whenever it makes sense to encapsulate behavior in objects. By using this approach:

- You comply with SRP
- It results in a high-cohesion design
- You achieve higher reusability

For example, one of the domain-driven design tactical patterns building blocks is **Value Object**. It is used to encapsulate behavior and reuse it to reduce the complexity of the domain by dividing the responsibilities into multiple coherent classes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is very close, and I will write a more detailed response with my findings. Encapsulation is part of it, but I ideally want to minimize behavior and focus on data constraints. As such, Value Object seems to be about as close as I'm going to get to what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The answer, currently, seems to be Value Objects. Value objects are an object meant to represent an immutable set of data with arbitrary constraints that can (and probably should be) enforced at construction time. You can find a video [here](https://youtu.be/P5CRea21R2E) that does a solid job of illustrating a motivation for value objects. Additionally, they use the [result](https://youtu.be/WCCkEe_Hy2Y) type to handle validation control, which is another separate problem that my question brought up.

Edit: Bonus, Traits seem to flirt with this concept. I also learned today that after v20 C++ has a new feature called [constraints](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) (and concepts) which, for typed languages, gets remarkably close to what I'm envisioning. In [this talk in 2022](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_doRiQS4GS8) around 42 minutes, you can see an interesting example of how this might look in practice in the function `isFirstElemTheSame`.

Credit and thanks to [@R.Abbasi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77633148/9217040) for the initial answer that prompted me to investigate value objects more, and
Milan Jovanović; the youtuber cited in the hyperlinks. Also Alex Dathskovsky from the conference link.

Comment: Value Objects are certainly one answer. But they are not the only answer. Value Objects do not necessarily constrain their primitive components; and conversely, non-value Objects _may_ constrain primitive components. You can achieve the goal with either one.